# Get batch size in Keras custom layer and use tensorflow operations (tf.Variable)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I would like to write a Keras custom layer with tensorflow operations, that require the batch size as input. Apparently I'm struggling in every nook and cranny.

Suppose a very simple layer:
(1) get batch size
(2) create a tf.Variable (let's call it my_var) based on the batch size, then some tf.random ops to alter my_var
(3) finally, return input multiplied with my_var

What I tried so far:

```
class TestLayer(Layer):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        self.num_batch = None
        self.my_var = None

        super(TestLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):

        self.batch_size = input_shape[0]

        var_init = tf.ones(self.batch_size, dtype = x.dtype)
        self.my_var = tf.Variable(var_init, trainable=False, validate_shape=False)

        # some tensorflow random operations to alter self.my_var

        super(TestLayer, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this at the end

    def call(self, x):

        return self.my_var * x

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):

        return input_shape
```

Now creating a very simple model:

```
# define model
input_layer = Input(shape = (2, 2, 3), name = 'input_layer')
x = TestLayer()(input_layer)

# connect model
my_mod = Model(inputs = input_layer, outputs = x)
my_mod.summary()
```

Unfortunately, what ever I try/change in the code, I get multiple errors, most of them with very cryptical tracebacks (ValueError: Cannot convert a partially known TensorShape to a Tensor:  or ValueError: None values not supported.).

Any general suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify batch size if you want to create a variable of size `batch_size`. Additionally, if you want to print a summary the `tf.Variable` must have a fixed shape (`validatate_shape=True`) and it must be broadcastable to be successfully multiplied by the input:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer, Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

class TestLayer(Layer):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.num_batch = None
        self.my_var = None
        super(TestLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.batch_size = input_shape[0]
        var_init = tf.ones(self.batch_size, dtype=tf.float32)[..., None, None, None]
        self.my_var = tf.Variable(var_init, trainable=False, validate_shape=True)
        super(TestLayer, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this at the end

    def call(self, x):
        res = self.my_var * x
        return res

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape

# define model
input_layer = Input(shape=(2, 2, 3), name='input_layer', batch_size=10)
x = TestLayer()(input_layer)

# connect model
my_mod = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=x)
my_mod.summary()
```

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_layer (InputLayer)     (10, 2, 2, 3)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
test_layer (TestLayer)       (10, 2, 2, 3)             0         
=================================================================
Total params: 0
Trainable params: 0
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Comment: Once again, thank you Vlad. Do you know what to do if I want arbitrary batch shape, as it is done within most of default layers (e.g. having None shape when i print the summary). For instance, Keras dropout layer does also depend on the batch shape to compute the noise shape mask (dropout mask: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/9d33a024e3893ec2a4a15601261f44725c6715d1/keras/layers/core.py#L110, then, keras calls tf dropout function: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/66b193faeecda4e6bc7e2767c2d927eecd199a34/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py#L4174).

Comment: Since you define a variable you can't define it with unknown shape dimension. The shape of the variable must be fully defined. Dropout layer doesn't use variables. In general you can use the unknown shapes for different operation (to get it use `tf.shape(tensor)`) but not for variables.

Comment: @Vlad Just wanted to ask for a clarification to your comment about dynamic shapes. What if I needed to create a new Tensor within call() method in a custom layer, which would support dynamic batch size. For example, some kind of a custom Embedding layer for text encoding, where inputs are (None, None) (batch, variable token length) and outputs are (None, 64). How in this case would I create an empty tensor with dynamic batch to fill it with weights depending on the inputs and return to the next layer?

Comment: @GlaIZier I am having trouble understanding what you are trying to achieve. Could you please post a question with example input and expected output? Please post a link to that question here so I could help you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70421012/how-to-define-a-new-tensor-with-a-dynamic-shape-to-support-batching-in-a-custom

It's already been answered, but if you know how to do it in a different way, I would be grateful to read